# Exclude items according to a record

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query excludes all the products however, I am trying to exclude the products only if the `R.OPERATING_UNITS = 'WP'`. I was not sure if I need to include the case statement in the where clause or not. I wanted to know what is the best efficient way to do that. Below is the query, the `RESOURCE` table and also the desired result set. I simplified both the table and query for the sake of explanation.

```
SELECT R.DEPTID,
       R.FISCAL_YEAR, 
       sum(R.AMOUNT) total
FROM   RESOURCE R 
WHERE 
 R.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_CAT='FUEL' )
 group by R.FISCAL_YEAR,R.DEPTID
```

the RESOURCE table

```
DPTID   FISCAL_YEAR OPERATING_UNIT  AMOUNT  
PTT         2017        WP      1200
PTT         2017        SP      3000
PTT         2017        GP      1000
FPP         2017        WP      1000
FPP         2018        GP      2000
FPP         2017        SP      1000
FPP         2018        SP      2000
```

Result set. Note that it is ignoring WP when calculating the sum.

```
2017    PTT 4000
2017    FPP 1000
2018    FPP 4000
```

Comment: no just the sql.thanks

Comment: What is `PR`? In your query there's not any table or alias with this name...

Comment: @OscarPérez, I fixed the typo, it should have been  R.

Comment: sounds like you want a conditional sum - i.e. `sum(case when operating_unit != 'WP' then amount end)` (Aggregate functions ignore null values; you could add an `else 0` clause into the case, but it won't change the result.). I suggest a conditional sum rather than adding an `operating_unit != 'WP'` predicate to the where clause, because if you only had a WP operating unit for a dptid, that row would be excluded entirely from the results, whereas it would appear in the conditional sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #resource
(
    DPTID varchar(10)
    ,FISCAL_YEAR varchar(10)
    ,OPERATING_UNIT varchar(10)
    ,AMOUNT int
)

insert into #resource
select 'PTT','2017','WP', 1200 union all
select 'PTT','2017','SP', 3000 union all
select 'PTT','2017','GP', 1000 union all
select 'FPP','2017','WP', 1000 union all
select 'FPP','2018','GP', 2000 union all
select 'FPP','2017','SP', 1000 union all
select 'FPP','2018','SP', 2000

select * from #resource

select FISCAL_YEAR,DPTID, SUM(AMOUNT) as Amount
from #resource
where OPERATING_UNIT <> 'WP'
group by FISCAL_YEAR,DPTID
order by FISCAL_YEAR,Amount desc


drop table #resource
```

output:

```
FISCAL_YEAR DPTID   Amount
2017        PTT     4000
2017        FPP     1000
2018        FPP     4000
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to all the non-WP products through like this:

```
SELECT R.DEPTID, R.FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(R.AMOUNT) total FROM RESOURCE R 
WHERE
    R.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_CAT = 'FUEL')
    OR R.OPERATING_UNITS <> 'WP' -- <<<========
GROUP BY R.DEPTID, R.FISCAL_YEAR
```

Of course you can also handle this with a join as I assume the inner join will work and is a one-to-one relationship:

```
SELECT R.DEPTID, R.FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(R.AMOUNT) total
FROM RESOURCE R INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_ID = R.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE
    P.PRODUCT_CAT <> 'FUEL' OR R.OPERATING_UNITS <> 'WP'
    -- by DeMorgan's Law this is equivalent:
    -- NOT (P.PRODUCT_CAT = 'FUEL' AND R.OPERATING_UNITS = 'WP')
GROUP BY R.DEPTID, R.FISCAL_YEAR
```