# Oracle, SQL Conditional exclusion based on the items in the joined table

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query excludes all the products however, I am trying to exclude the products "only if" the `R.OPERATING_UNITS = 'WP'` and `PRODUCT_CAT = 'FUEL'` in the joined table. I don't know how to condition that. I wanted to know what is the best efficient way to do that. Below is the query, the `RESOURCE`, `PRODUCT` table and also the desired result set. I simplified both the tables and query for the sake of explanation.

```
SELECT R.DEPTID,
       R.FISCAL_YEAR, 
       sum(R.AMOUNT) total
FROM   RESOURCE R 
WHERE 
 R.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_CAT='FUEL' )
 group by R.FISCAL_YEAR,R.DEPTID
```

the RESOURCE table

```
DPTID   FISCAL_YEAR OPERATING_UNIT  AMOUNT  PRODUCT
PTT         2017        WP      1200    31000
PTT         2017        SP      3000    32000
PTT         2017        GP      1000    31000
PTT         2017        WP      1000    32000
FPP         2017        WP      1000    32000
FPP         2018        GP      2000    33000
FPP         2017        SP      1000    32000
FPP         2018        WP      2200    31000
```

PRODUCT Table:

```
PRODUCT     PRODUCT_CAT 
31000       FUEL
32000       NON-FUEL
33000       MATERIAL
```

Result set. Note that it is ignoring WP when calculating the sum.

```
2017    PTT 5000  (igonred 1200 since operating unit=wp and product is 31000->FUEL but included wp and 32000)
2017    FPP 2000
2018    FPP 2000    (it did not consider the 2200 since operating unit=wp and product is 31000->FUEL)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude items according to a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930951/exclude-items-according-to-a-record)

Comment: @Kobi - this is definitely not a duplicate; the base data is the same, and the question may look similar but it is in fact very different. The OP should have **deleted** the earlier question, if it wasn't in fact his or her true question. The one posted here does make sense.

Comment: It often helps if you write your query in a way that follows your logic. To see which rows must be excluded, you need to have the data joined already - the condition is based on data from both tables. So your SQL code should reflect that. You need a WHERE clause where both relevant columns are checked *at the same time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP filter should work after you change below statement

```
NOT IN (
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_CAT='FUEL' )
```

and then you can filter operating unit.

```
SELECT R.DEPTID,
       R.FISCAL_YEAR, 
       sum(R.AMOUNT) total
FROM   RESOURCE R 
WHERE 
r.OPERATING_UNIT  = 'WG' and 
 R.PRODUCT_ID IN
 (
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_CAT='FUEL' )
 group by R.FISCAL_YEAR,R.DEPTID
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking in a not-equal to clause with an OR in-between should filter out the cases where both OperatingUnit = 'WP' & ProductCat = 'Fuel'

```
SELECT r.DEPTID
      ,r.FISCAL_YEAR
      ,SUM(r.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
FROM [Resource] r
     INNER JOIN [Product] p ON r.PRODUCT = p.PRODUCT
WHERE r.OPERATING_UNIT != 'WP'
      OR p.PRODUCT_CAT != 'FUEL'
GROUP BY r.DEPTID
        ,r.FISCAL_YEAR
```

I used the following query below to view the data and verify that it's returning the 6/8 rows I wanted.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Resource] r
     INNER JOIN [Product] p ON r.PRODUCT = p.PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 1):

For ease of writing - and reading - the exclusion condition, it would be nice if we could work with tuples. And we can. One benefit is that it will be easy, in the future, to add other pairs of operating unit and product category to the exclusion list, without having to write lengthy conditions with lots of OR and AND.

If you run a query like this, and then you take a look at the EXPLAIN PLAN for the query, you will see that the parser expanded the tuple condition to a long logical expression with OR (and AND, if more than one tuple is excluded) - so the end result is the same, but the code looks more natural.

```
select   r.deptid, r.fiscal_year, sum(r.amount) as total
from     resource r inner join product p on r.product = p.product
where    (r.operating_unit, p.product_cat) not in ( ('WP', 'FUEL') )
group by r.deptid, r.fiscal_year
;
```

Regarding `NULL`: if either `r.operating_unit` or `p.product_cat` can be `NULL`, you need to state how they should be handled. If, for example, the operating unit is WP but the product category is `NULL`, the corresponding row will be excluded in the query above. That may be the proper handling: the unit is definitely 'WP', and since we don't know the product category, we must make a decision. Since it *may* be 'FUEL', we just don't know for sure, we may choose to exclude it. Obviously, if both columns are `NOT NULL` then this is not an issue.

Note - I hope you don't really have a table `PRODUCT` with a column `PRODUCT`; that will lead to confusion which almost always then leads to bugs.